# Malformed SQLite Database Without Exception Being Thrown

Tags: android, sqlite, malformed

I have an SQLite database with records being inserted into it for my Android app.

I am inserting the answers to on screen surveys, with one answer saved per row in my table.

My surveys have 20 questions, and it inserts the answers correctly to the database for the first survey, but then when I insert the answers for the second survey (programatically the same questions, just done again) it malforms the database, but never throws an exception or anything.  I run an integrity check before and after and it always returns true.

The unusual thing is that it is only malformed when I try to look at the table on my computer.  I tried using the SQLite Database Browser tool, TKSQLite tool, and then opening the DB from the supplied sqlite3.exe, and they all seem to show the DB as malformed.  Although the TKSQLite tool notifies me that the table is malformed, I can get the data in other tables.  The SQLite Database Browser just shows no data in the table, and sqlite3.exe won't open any tables.

The very unusual thing is if I query the table in the app and print the cursor rows out to log cat, or use the data within the app, all the data is there.

Has anyone seen only partial malformation without an exception being thrown?  I would like my database to be pristine...but if my data is there can I hope that it won't get any more malformed?

I worked with SQLite databases for a few projects now doing similar things, and this is the first time I am seeing only partial malformation.

If it will help I am using the Acer a501 tablet programming on Honeycomb 3.2

Additionally, I am accessing the database using a static singleton, to avoid opening and closing the database too often for each insert, and originally inserted via SQL commands using `execSQL()`, but have also tried using the SQLiteDatabase method `insert()` to no avail.

Comment: I don't see any information we can use to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out why the database was malforming but not on the device.  The tablet we are using is counted as a Portable Media Device according to Windows, and there was some issue when we copied it from the device to the computer.  Using a thumb drive to copy to from the device and then from the thumb drive to Windows solved the problem.